# How to implement iPhone scroll in android gallery class

Tags: android, gallery

I want to add scroll beyond views in gallery and fling back.Effect like iPhone when scrolling on edge view.

Comment: Apple has a patent on that effect, btw.

Comment: Actually, Apple was sued because someone else already had a patent on it before them (supposedly, I believe the wording was vague)

Comment: Are you joking?)This effect is emplement in contacts view,for example,when you are scrolling above first contact.